# Typescript Derived Class Must contain super call on all execution paths

Tags: typescript

Im working on a Derived Class from Map

I have most of it working but i would like to be able to take an array as a param for a constructor, just like Map does. An example

```
return new Map([...this.entries()].filter(([k, v]) => search(v)))
```

I'd like to have the option of this in my derived class. My attempt:

```
constructor();
constructor(array: ([TKey, TVal])[]);
constructor(array?: ([TKey, TVal])[]) {
  if (array != null)
    super(array);
  else
     super();
 }
```

However the message I'm getting is:

> Derived Class Must contain super call on all execution paths

I guess It seems like all paths are good to me. how should i approach this? Inmy case? And in general, just in case something with spread or the like solves my specific problem?

Comment: What version of TypeScript and what environment are you using to get that error message? The TypeScript Playground seems to think your code is valid: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuAeWBpeBPANHAamCAHzTwAeS8AdgCYwCyYADmprgUaQN4BQ0A6MAD21ZACcArsCTDxACgCUAbn6CRYpFJlz5YceLBYAXNHkBtDNjyxCIALqLzj1YKGiJ02Qv2GsAflMLKw5bIkdnRWg+NzcASwAzM18jaABCAF5oakkQEEU1WNiISWZ4HwMjFULY+BAIeBqigRKyhWq3AF9eTqA

Comment: I'm using typescript 3.4 and working in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: @Seth I tried this scenario with both vs 2019 and ts 3.4 and I was unable to reproduce. It seems like it is not code related but environmental.

Comment: Found the culprit - resharper. Wasn't thinking about that.